# asp:button reloads the page instead of firing OnClick event in Sitecore

Tags: html, asp.net, sitecore

I am using Sitecore and I have a header sublayout that I use in all pages. This layout contains a Logout button that fires OnClick event when clicked and executes the onclick event function. But in few pages it wont fire OnClick event at all instead it reloads the page.

Below is the code for the logout button

```
<asp:button id="btnLogout" runat="server" borderstyle="None" onclick="btnLogout_Click" text="Log out" ToolTip="Log out" backcolor="Transparent" style="cursor:pointer" class="logout_new"></asp:button>
```

Below is the code for the event function

```
protected void btnLogout_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{              
   Sitecore.Security.Authentication.AuthenticationManager.Logout();
   Response.Redirect("/Login.aspx");
}
```

I found out that the difference between the pages where the logout fires the onclick event and pages where it does'nt is that they use the same header sublayout containing the logout button but they use different content sublayout though.

Note: I have not applied Cache to any sublayout.

Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: Do you mean a Sublayout? (an ascx) Did you apply cache to the sublayout?

Comment: yes it is a sublayout. I have not applied cache to the sublayout

Comment: Do you have any JavaScript that binds to the button? Perhaps in some cases you have a click handler in JS that may return false and thus prevents the postback.

Comment: @MarkUrsino I found out that the problem was in the content sublayout where it was not working, the Page_Load function was calling a Response.Redirect function to itself and it was not checking if it was a post back request or not before that. I noticed that in the other content sublayout where it was working, it was checking if it was a not a post back. I added a if(!IsPostBack) before that and it started working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was in the content sublayout in which it was not working, the Page_Load function was calling a Response.Redirect function to itself and it was not checking if it was a post back request or not before that. So Whenever a user clicked logout button it used to post it back to the server and the page used to reload instead of executing the onclick event.

I noticed that in the other content sublayout  where it was working, it was checking if it was a post back or not.

I added a if(!IsPostBack) before that and it started working.

Answer (score 2):

From the given context I don’t know what is the issue but here is what I will do if I have issue like this.

As you said only on few pages it is not working, it could be the other controls on that particular page is causing the issue.

I will pick two pages which has less controls on the presentation layer. Say PageA is a working page and PageB is a non-working page. Then I compare PageA and PageB and remove all common controls, this should narrow down the number of the controls on the presentation layer. Now check again to see if Page B is working or not. If not, I will try to remove one control at a time on PageB untill it starts working. If you find by removing certain control and the page started working then you can look into the particular control and identify the issue.

I hope this helps.

Comment: I took your advice and tested. The problem was in the content sublayout where it was not working the PageLoad function was calling a redirect function to itself and it was not checking if it was post back request or not before that like in the sublayouts where it was working. I added a if(!IsPostBack) before that and it started working.

Answer (score 0):

try disabling the cache as it would return the html without triggering the back end code.
To do so, one option is going to the presentation detail of those pages, find the control and click on it to edit. Under the "Caching section" uncheck "Cacheable" and publish the item. If this fixes your problem, I'd review the standard values of the template, to apply the change to all the items with the same template

Comment: @vincent yeah it is a sublayout. how do i disable the caching?

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.

Comment: One option is going to the presentation detail of those pages, find the control and click on it to edit. Under the "Caching section" uncheck "Cacheable" and publish the item. If this fixes your problem, I'd review the standard values of the template, to apply the change to all the items with the same template.

Comment: @askb, I've rewritten it. Better now?

Comment: You can also load your page, go to `/sitecore/admin/showcache.aspx` and clear the caches. Then go back and click your button, if it hits your breakpoint/works then it is a caching issue. You can also set `cacheHtml="false"` on the `<site>` node, but you know, only for testing purposes :)

Comment: @VicentGaliana I editted the control by going to the presentation detail and i found that its already unchecked. Anyways I saved it and published. It is still not working.

Comment: @jammykam I cleared the cache and tried again and its still not working though

Answer (score 0):

This behavior happens to me at annoying times too, but it's almost always the same thing: the Sitecore sublayout the code is in is being cached.

The onclick javascript fires, but the page is not re-rendered with new content because the "unclicked" version is stored in the cache.

You'll need to disable caching on the sublayout to make the button work.

This can, however, be somewhat annoying if you're trying to cache as much presentation stuff as you can. In those cases, it often means you need to, counter-intuitively, create a number of "sub-sublayouts" and place them statically. Set the containing sublayout to be uncached, and then you can set each smaller one's caching appropriately (caching static parts, not caching dynamic stuff).

Comment: I found out that the caching was already disabled. I anyway saved it and republished. It is still not working though.